# Cambiar de JavaScript a php extrayendo datos de Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy configurando un mapa de Google con los `markerclusterer`. Pero ahora mismo estoy metiendo las localizaciones con JavaScript.

Código:

```
var locations = [
    {lat: 39.4685293, lng: -0.39684460000000854},
    {lat: 39.57896239999999, lng: -0.32614809999995487},
    {lat: 38.8881041, lng: -0.4944843000000674},
    {lat: 39.1925693, lng: -0.4337304000000586},
    {lat: 39.4716426, lng: -0.3927757000000156},
    {lat: 39.195919, lng: -0.4334797000000208},
    {lat: 39.5652461, lng: -0.5277914000000692},
    {lat: 39.5462314, lng: -0.5775444999999308},
    {lat: 39.4738675, lng: -0.4578721000000314},
    {lat: 39.6637152, lng: -0.23545050000006995},
    {lat: 39.4320763, lng: -0.37652909999997064},
    {lat: 38.9726585, lng: -0.1741809000000103},
    {lat: 39.0731451, lng: -0.260875800000008},
    {lat: 39.14787, lng: -0.4367499999999609},
    {lat: 39.2862481, lng: -0.423973100000012},
    {lat: 39.1929618, lng: -0.43194389999996474},
    {lat: 39.4658339, lng: -0.3671825000000126},
    {lat: 39.4983147, lng: -0.43599010000002636}
];
```

Pero claro, estas localizaciones las tengo que sacar de la Base de datos. Es un problema que no sé darle solución, no sé si se puede crear un `while` o un `foreach` y sacar los datos de `lat` y `lng` de la base de datos con JavaScript o bien como tendría que hacer esto. No he llegado hacer ninguna prueba, ya que no sé cómo proceder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quitamos las localizaciones y ponemos un **include** de php donde generaremos un **while** con las latitudes y longitudes.

```
var locations = [
    <?php include('php/marcadores.php'); ?>
];
```

Archivo **marcadores.php**:

```
include "../conexion/conecta.php";

// Listamos las direcciones con todos sus datos (lat, lng, dirección, etc.)
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM centros");

// Seleccionamos los datos para crear los marcadores en el Mapa de Google serian direccion, lat y lng
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '{lat:' . $row['latitud'] . ', lng:' . $row['longitud'] . '},';
}
```